# Access to TextView in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have a *ViewPager* in my main Activity and make a *TextView* on every page.

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int counterID) {
        TextView counter = new TextView(cxt);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(counter, 0);
        return counter;
    }
```

*TextView* shows counter value and I want to change it on active page (TextView text) using the method I implemented in the same Activity with *PagerAdapter*.

Is there any way to access *TextView* on specific page outside of *PagerAdapter* (in the same Activity) and change its attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an ID to the TextView by calling

```
textview.setId(int id);
```

Then you can find your view by `(TextView) findViewById(int id)`

or you can set a Tag on the textview:

`textview.setId(Object tag);` and find the view via `(TextView) findViewWithTag (Object tag)`

Comment: I think you mean `setTag()` on the second one, no?